# HTML Agility Pack - Get Text From DIV with Align=left style

Tags: c#, xpath, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I want to know how to get the text from a DIV with align=left style?

Here is my code so far of my xpath query, my only problem is in here I dont know if my xpath query is correct.

I think the problem is in the [@align='left]' code of my xpath query.

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@align='left']");
```

Comment: Looks OK. What's the problem? Any errors? Exceptions? What exactly is not working? The `nodes` variable should contain a node collection with those nodes.

Comment: i think @align='left' in the code is not correct..i'm not getting the text in the div tag

Comment: How have you accessed the text of each of the selected nodes? You didn't who that code.

Comment: Attribute value selectors were added recently I believe... They used to be unsupported. Which version of HAP are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest HAP

Answer (score 0):

`HtmlNode.SelectNodes` method selects a list of nodes matching the xpath expression passed. You need to iterate these nodes and get the `InnerHtml` (or `InnerText`) of each item like this:

```
// check if nodes found
if (nodes != null)
    foreach (var div in nodes)
    {
        var html = div.InneHtml;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already have that in my code. My only problem is in the xpath query.

Comment: @user1307655, your xpath looks OK. I tried it out, and it selects the divs with `align` attribute set to `left` for me.

Comment: Make sure you check for a `null` outcome. The HAP returns null, not an empty collection if it can't find any nodes: `var nodes = (doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@align='left']") ?? new HtmlNodeCollection(null));`

Comment: @jessehouwing, there is already a check for `null` in the code snippet I provided